# Inkscape unnecessary color change

Tags: inkscape, color

I have a problem with the many color changes. I encountered this problem while trying to do a multicolored project. As you can see on the first screenshot [image] it has way too many color changes which seem unnecessary. Isn't there a way where I can set it up so it I can decide which color it should begin to stitch? I found a tutorial on youtube which showed me a way: Selecting every thing in order you want it to sticht (I selected yellow first, then red, then black until I was finished) after that you go to Extensions -> Inkstitch -> Edit -> Re-Stack objects in order of selection. I also clicked that and suddenly the image turned black. I tried another order but then it wasn't showing all the colors.

Is there a way where I can decide the order?
Is there a way where you can lower the color change so you don't have to switch all the time.

Additional 1: [image]
Additional 2: [image]

Answer (score 1):

I have little to no experience using the Inkstitch extension. It's somewhat specialist and I'm not sure if many graphic designers will have experience with it.

However, there is [a tutorial on youtube](https://youtu.be/v3uE1dHAwBc?si=O1fqGFe1pW7BA8Bs&t=608), where it is mentioned that Inkstitch uses the order of the Objects in the Objects panel, and starts stitching from the bottom object up.

This panel is now called the Layers and Objects panel in the most recent version of Inkscape.  You can reorder the objects in the stack by clicking and dragging them to a different position.

You might also want to try manually renaming the objects in the panel so you can easily keep track of them and put them in the correct order.  Adding the name of the colour for each object could be helpful.

Anyway, here's an example

[image]

I also see that in your screenshot you have two groups, and one of them is nested within the other. It might be a good idea to ungroup these. I don't know how well or even if Inkstitch can deal with groups. Nested groups can cause issues in some graphics applications, so you may as well get rid of them if you don't need them.